# Question on Properties of Eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra

Given a vector v and matrix A,

v = \begin{bmatrix}1\\-3\\0\end{bmatrix}

A= \begin{bmatrix}4&1&1\\6&3&2\\-3&-1&0\end{bmatrix}

Find Av. Then say what that means about the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of A.

I know that it returns the same vector so you would know the matrix is invertible, though I don't know how that affects the eigenvalues/eigenvectos. I am not really sure where this question is going though. Thanks

Comment: It just says that $v$ is an eigenvector of $A$  associated to the eigenvalue $\lambda = 1$. It's the definition of eigenvalues in action.

Comment: "*I know it returns the same vector so you know the matrix is invertible*"  That is false logic.  All that it tells you is that the vector is in the range as well.  You can have $Av=v$ in scenarios where $A$ is noninvertible.  What you need to remember is the definition of eigenvalues and eigenvectors.  An eigenvalue-eigenvector pair is a pair: a scalar $\lambda$ and a vector $v$ such that $Av = \lambda v$.  I.e. the matrix acts on eigenvectors the same as scalar multiplication by their respective eigenvalues.

Comment: For counter-example to your claim "*it returns... is invertible*", consider $\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$ and the vector $\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}$.  Clearly the matrix is not invertible.

Comment: Ok right. So the purpose of the question is just to recognize that v is an eigenvector? And is the fact that you know it is associated to lambda=1 based off of how it returns the same vector?

Answer (score 0):

Calculate Av, and see if the result of Av is the same as some scalar times v. If it does, then by definition, that scalar is an eigenvalue and v here is the eigenvector corresponding to that eigenvalue.

I guess that's what the question is asking. Hope this helps.